Project with Auth0, Contentful and Nextjs14
"I need to do a blog project with these technologies. It will be my first professional project and I'm a little lost. Should I start with the database using Contentful, with Auth0, or with the front-end part?
Thank you so much!"
I need a guide to do my project correctly.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

How did you handle this. Join Contentful's Discord community!
